# action future_post returns wrong date

Tags: actions

Hi I am using a `future_post` hook to capture when a scheduled post is updated like so :

```
add_action('future_post', 'on_post_scheduled');
```

Then I want to send the new post date to a database, however `$post->post_date` returns the date prior to updating the post. I have to update the post again to get the correct new  date.

Within the `on_post_scheduled` function I am using the `global $post` to access the post date, is this the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function on_post_scheduled( $post_id, $post ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;
    // If this is a 'post' post and post status is future.
    if ( ('post' == $post->post_type) && ('future' == $post->post_status)) {
        // do the thing zhu li!
        wp_die('<pre>'.print_r($post,true).'</pre>');
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'on_post_scheduled', 10, 2 );
```

it's best to add action on save_post like this... and just check the post type and post status...

Comment: Thanks Reigel, How does this solve the date being wrong?

Comment: `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated. So before it saves the all the data, it goes in this action.... try do a return false here and data are not saved...

Comment: I put there `wp_die('<pre>'.print_r($post,true).'</pre>');` for you to see if the date is correct... For which I'm confident it is...